# fosuser register for admin only

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, role

My goal is to make the register form private (for admins only) (to just register people)

So I override Default FOSUserBundle Form register to add more attributs that I created.

The problem is that I made all my website not allowed by anonymous. But I still register !
How can I change in fosuserbundle to make the registerform private.

What is wierd is when I am logged in I can go in all my pages and see that I am, but when I go to the register form it didn't see that I am (that's the problem) so if I put in my security.yml the line for register it doesn't work because it doesn't see that I am logged in

```
access_control:
     - { path: furter/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: furter/register/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

If I let the last line I got this :

"**Full authentication is required to access this resource.**"

I think I will need to write a addUser and create everything, but is there a way ?

I don't know what code I need to show you, but it doesn't seems like it would help.

Cheers !

Comment: i use: { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN } and it works.

Comment: ok, it doesn't work with me, what is your register route ? I called the defaut one (fos_user_registration_register)

Comment: If everybody having this probleme check all your firewall, I had one firewall with register anonymous allowed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your security rule is not correct, remove the '/' at the end of route and it should work

```
- { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```